# normalization of reservation database

Tags: database, database-design

hi im developing a online reservation of a event place my issue is in the module of ticketing if a client booked two functionroom in one ticket im not sure with my database if it is full normalized i just want to be sure please leave comment for database improvement

```
create table RESERVATIONS (
PK reservation_id
 lname,
 fname,
 contact,
 email,
 date,
 timeStart,
 timeEnd
 numGuest,
 total)

 create table FUNCTIONROOMS (
PK function_id,
FK functionroom_id,
FK reservation_id)

 create table FUNCTIONROOMDETAILS(
PK functionroom_id,
 functionName,
 functionPrice,
 functionStatus)
```

im planning for this query is my database normalized? or not

```
select functionRoom.functionRoom_id  
from reservations, functionRoom
where reservation.reservation_id = functionRoom.reservation_id
and reservation_id = 'reservation_id'
```

Comment: Normalization is not related to the expected queries; there are several forms of normalization; `RESERVATIONS` doesn't seem to have a column `reservation_id`.  Oh, and you should go accept some answers.

Comment: thanks i forgot to add the reservation_id but it has i already updated the post :),

Comment: What are the `PRIMARY` keys of the tables? What are the relationships (`FOREIGN` keys) between tables? What do these tables represent? Where are the tables that represent Rooms, Clients, Events (that you mention in your question)?

Comment: @ypercube it represent in the module reserving the client
i dont have a room clients and events table 
the project has no rooms it is a open place 3 function room actualy 
i refere them in the functionroom table

Comment: @Led, No keys, no constraints, no data types and only some inaccurate pseudo-code to go on. This isn't even a database design - let alone a normalized one. No one can tell you accurately if it is normalized without knowing what the keys are and what dependencies it is supposed to satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

Your tables doesn't seem to be normalized, there is no apparent primary key in Reservation.

Normalization is quite a topic, and there are several levels of normal forms, you can use just the ones you need.

And as Jim Garrison said in the comments queries can't be normalized, so your last question doesn't have a clear answer.

Comment: i forgot to add the reservation_id but i aleady update the post, may i ask if my database is proper nomalized?

Comment: I am afraid not. There are several levels of normalization (the normal forms). Your database may be in the first normal form, but not in the second, or it may be in the second but not in the third. In the first case your database wasn't even in the first form, now It looks like it could be in the first. If you want to learn more about normalization look for explanations on the web (wikipedia, etc), it could help you a lot. It could be better if you give more details about your tables and data types, as said in the comments by @sqlvogel.